# Parse a plist file with swift Codable using PropertyListDecoder and maintain sorting of dictionaries

Tags: swift, plist, codable, ordereddictionary

I need to parse a plist in swift and maintain sorting of entries in plist dictionaries.
The preferred parsing method would be using the `Codable` protocol as I want to make custom objects from my plist.

I have set up the following example:

```
// example plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>container</key>
    <dict>
        <key>first</key>
        <string>Rocinante</string>
        <key>second</key>
        <string>Donnager</string>
        <key>third</key>
        <string>Behemoth</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>


// example parsing code (playground-ready)
import Foundation

let plistURL: URL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "plist")!
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: plistURL)
let decoder = PropertyListDecoder()

let result = try! decoder.decode(Model.self, from: data)

struct Model: Decodable {
    let container: Dictionary<String, String> // sure enough entries are in random order :(
}
```

I tried using the new `OrderedDictionary` from [swift-collections](https://github.com/apple/swift-collections) but it does not conform to the Codable protocol.

Maybe some custom parsing into Array or OrderedDictionary would work but I did not figure out how to do this yet (or if it is even possible).

So – how can I parse a plist with `Codable` while maintaining dictionary ordering?

Comment: Why can't you have type as array  in plist for key "Container", instead of dictionary? Dictionaries are unordered, so they won't help in achieving your desired output.

Comment: The plist data is given – I cannot change the format

Comment: A dictionary has no order. You need to accept that.

Comment: And yet popular plist editors manage to maintain them. So no, not accepting.