# Swift XMLParser refuses to parse xml file with 'plist' extension

Tags: swift, plist, nsxmlparser

I have found a strange behavior when trying to parse a (xml-)plist file using `XMLParser`:
Parsing fails apparently just because of the 'plist'-extension – every other extension seems to work:

```
import Foundation

let plistURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "plist")! // valid xml-plist
let fooURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "foo")! // duplicate, renamed extension

let plistSuccess = XMLParser(contentsOf: plistURL)!.parse()   // false
let fooSuccess = XMLParser(contentsOf: fooURL)!.parse()       // true
```

Side note: The reason I am trying `XMLParser` instead of `PropertyListSerialization` or `Codable` is that the latter mess up ordering of dictionaries, which I need to maintain. ([Parse a plist file with swift Codable using PropertyListDecoder and maintain sorting of dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67745702/parse-a-plist-file-with-swift-codable-using-propertylistdecoder-and-maintain-sor?noredirect=1#comment119745004_67745702))

How can I make this work short of renaming the file?

Comment: What's strange to me is that you are force-unwrapping an optional value.

Comment: Well this is demo code to show the issue as concise as possible!